# Symfony and React within a Docker-Container: Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack

Tags: reactjs, docker, symfony

I am trying to run nginx, symfony and react within a docker container.

I am getting this error when loading the page:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Could not find the entrypoints file from Webpack: the file "/var/www/html/public/build/entrypoints.json" does not exist.").
```

I have consulted the following documentaries yet:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/faq.html#uncaught-referenceerror-webpackjsonp-is-not-defined

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack

My package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^4.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Basisimage
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Installiere Abhängigkeiten
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo_pgsql \
    intl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
RUN npm install -g yarn

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . .

# Installiere Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Installiere die Composer-Abhängigkeiten
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader

# Setze die Dateiberechtigungen
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/var

RUN yarn add webpack-notifier@^1.15.0 --dev

RUN yarn build

# Exponiere den Container-Port
EXPOSE 9000

# Starte den PHP-FPM-Server
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

The webpack.config.js:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .enableReactPreset()
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabel(() => {}, {
        useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        corejs: 3
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

If anything was working correctly, I Hello World should be printed in a h1 react-tag.

Due to the documentary, I have consulted, the build process must be correct. Have looked within the docker container, if the file was build somewhere else, but it did not generate at all.

The whole project can be found here: https://gitlab.technik-emden.de/ch6447/HardwareBookingSystem